# Modify attributes (including queue) of a pbs jobs

Tags: hpc, torque

I want to change the attributes (walltime and queue) of several (idle) jobs scheduled on a cluster.

When I do (where 1234 is the job id):

```
qalter -l walltime=24:00:00 -q newQueue 1234
```

I get the following **error**:

```
qalter: illegally formed job identifier: newQueue
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in two steps:

1. `qalter` to change the walltime

   ```
   qalter -l walltime=24:00:00 1234
   ```
2. `qmove` to move the job to newQueue

   ```
   qmove newQueue 1234
   ```

This order might be important, if newQueue is restricted for a maximum walltime of 24 hours (and the jobs were scheduled for a longer maximum walltime before).